# Why is my code not tracking score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script for tracking my score, I attached it to my player object, and of course attached my UI text object to it. I get no errors whatsoever, yet the text doesn't change, it stays at 0.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreTracker : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text scoreText;

    static int playerScore = 0;

    void Start () {

        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString ();

    }


    void Update () {

        playerScore += (int)Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `Time.deltaTime` when you call `Update()`?

Comment: Do you want your score to be increased by 1 for every second along the game?

Comment: @WeryNguyen Yeah. Well, a bit more than that but yeah that's the basic idea. Its a sidescroller so as long as you dont die you should see the counter go up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update() method is called approximately 60 times per sec (depend on your fps setting) and deltaTime is the different of the time from the last Update call. Therefore, most of the time `deltaTime` value = 1/60, and to convert to int, it will always be 0. Try the below code:

```
public class ScoreTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    static int playerScore = 0;

    public int nextScoreAtSecond = 1;
    float timeIncrease;


    void Start()
    {
        timeIncrease = 0;
        UpdateScore();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        timeIncrease += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeIncrease > nextScoreAtSecond)
        {
            // reset the time counter
            timeIncrease = 0;
            playerScore = playerScore + 1;
            UpdateScore();
        }
    }

    void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oohh okay, so I just didn't know how exactly deltatime worked. Thanks a lot, I guess next time I'll read the documentation first.

Answer (score 2):

`Start()` will only run once, so if you want to update your label in your `Update()` you should add a `scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString ();` after increasing the score

Comment: Yeah I know, but I tried that and it didn't work, I'm really confused.

Comment: So try adding an actual int (like @wvisaacs suggested). deltaTime is a small float, so when cast to int it is probably truncated to 0

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you simply increment?

```
playerscore++;
```

Time.deltaTime may be returning a value smaller than 1.

Comment: It does, actually. But why would using time.deltatime not make the number change at all?

Comment: @OfficerVimes _"Time.deltaTime may be returning a value smaller than 1."_